# pandas pivot table strange results

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I am have some trouble with grouping by pandas pivot table. I have a dataset and I am taking two subsets of it. 
Here is how I create the subsets and how they look like

```
df3= df2.head(170).tail()
df3
    cuts    delta_2 tag
165 (360, 2000] 426.0   0.0
166 (360, 2000] 426.0   0.0
167 (360, 2000] 426.0   0.0
168 (360, 2000] 426.0   0.0
169 NaN NaN 0.0

df4= (df2.head(171)).tail()
df4    
    cuts    delta_2 tag
166 (360, 2000] 426.0   0.0
167 (360, 2000] 426.0   0.0
168 (360, 2000] 426.0   0.0
169 NaN NaN 0.0
170 (180, 360]  183.0   0.0
```

Now I am just trying to group them using pivot tables and I get strange results:

```
df3.pivot_table(values = 'tag', index= 'cuts', aggfunc=['sum', 'count'],dropna=True).sort_values('cuts')
    sum count
    tag tag
cuts        
NaN 0.0 0
(360, 2000] 0.0 4
```

The above seems to have not counted anything for `NaN` category. However issue becomes much bigger in following

```
df4.pivot_table(values = 'tag', index= 'cuts', aggfunc=['sum', 'count'],dropna=True).sort_values('cuts')
    sum count
    tag tag
cuts        
NaN 0.0 3
(180, 360]  0.0 0
(360, 2000] 0.0 1
```

Here counting gets really weird. I am not able to figure out why. Variable `Cuts` was created using `pd.cut` function on the variable `delta_2`. My objective is just to get `mean` but since `mean` was showing strange results, I tried to calculate `sum` and `count`.

Answer (score 1):

```
df3.pivot_table(values = 'tag', index= 'cuts', aggfunc=[np.sum, 
np.mean],dropna=True).sort_values('cuts')
```

use numpy sum and numpy mean to compute the sum and mean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but any leads on why normal `sum` and `mean` do not work? I can get the results using `np.sum()` or even simple `groupby` but question is not about getting the solution, my question is why this does not work, or if I am making a mistake in doing this.